# ¿Cómo actualizar un solo campo tipo Blob de una tabla de mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

¿Cómo podría actualizar un solo campo de una tabla de mysql con hibernate utilizando `sesion.update`?

En el objeto profile tengo solo asignado el `id_profile` y una foto tipo `blob`.

Solo necesito actualizar el campo foto más no los otros campos que tengo en la tabla.

El código que que estoy utilizando:

```
public static boolean actualizarProfile(Profile profile) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();


        try{
            session.beginTransaction();     
            session.update(profile);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.disconnect();
            return true;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error en el metodo actualizarAccount - " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }finally {
            session.disconnect();
        }

}
```

Comment: Recomendación al margen, usa la anotación @Transactional para evitar abrir y cerrar las transacciones de forma manual. Una lectura en español http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/servicios/madeja/contenido/recurso/170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el código, parece que el objeto `Profile profile` no está asociado (attached) a una sesión de Hibernate. Por ello, cuando realices un `update` lo que hará Hibernate es:

1. Asociar el objeto `Profile` con la información actual de base de datos.
2. Hacer una "mezcla" (merge) del objeto obtenido de base de datos y del objeto que estás enviando, indicando los nuevos valores que se encuentran en el objeto enviado (en este caso, tu objeto `profile` que posiblemente tiene los demás campos en `null`).
3. Ejecutar el UPDATE respectivo.

Puedes revisar si realmente está actualizando todas las columnas habilitando a Hibernate que muestre los queries que ejecuta mediante la propiedad `hibernate.show_sql=true` y comprobar el efecto que te comento.

Para resolver este tema, tienes 3 opciones disponibles:

1. Ejecutar un query donde actualices solo el campo que necesitas:

   ```
   String hql = "UPDATE Profile SET photo = :photo WHERE id = :id";
   int result = session.createQuery(hql)
       .setParameter("photo", profile.getPhoto())
       .setParameter("id", profile.getId())
       .executeUpdate();
   ```
2. Obtener la entidad desde Hibernate con su información, setear el campo que necesitas y mandar a actualizarlo:

   ```
   Profile profileDB = session.get(Profile.class, profile.getId());
   profileDB.setPhoto(profile.getPhoto());
   session.update(profileDB);
   ```

   A pesar de ser menor código que el anterior, puede que esta alternativa cueste más tiempo de ejecución puesto que debe obtener el objeto de base de datos, lo cual puede incluir cargar una foto cargada anteriormente y/u otros objetos que están asociados a la clase (dolor en el tiempo de latencia del servidor por información que no se necesita), adicional se volverán a actualizar los antiguos elementos de tu clase
3. Configurar tu clase para que trabaje como dynamic-update. Esta es una "mejora" al trabajo anterior puesto que tu objeto anterior solo actualizará los campos que realmente han sido modificados. Para ello, debes cambiar tu clase así:

   ```
   @Entity
   @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
       dynamicUpdate = true
   )
   public class Profile implements java.io.Serializable {
       //fields and other things in your class
   }
   ```

   El código para actualizar los datos es idéntico al de la forma 2.

Answer (score 0):

En Hibernate o EclipseLink, los cambios serán aplicables a los campos que se vean modificados. Te pregunta no tiene una respuesta concreta, simplemente es:

```
// photo es un byte[]
profile.setPhoto(photo);
// persistes los datos
hibernate.merge(profile);
```

Comment: Cuidado. Puede que `profile` sea un objeto que no está atachado a la sesión de Hibernate, por lo cual si solo posee los campos `id` y `photo` con valores y los demás se encuentran en `null` por defecto Hibernate actualizará todos los campos.

Comment: ¿sucede también en JPA con Hibernate, @LuiggiMendoza?

Comment: Dependerá de la implementación a usar de JPA. No sé de EclipseLink porque no trabajo con él, pero de Hibernate sí lo he comprobado, puedes habilitar `hibernate.show_sql` y ver el query. Es más, mkyong escribió un tutorial al respecto: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-dynamic-update-attribute-example/

Comment: Gracias por la info y el link. Voy a echarle un ojo.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo así a la hora se guardar:

```
session.merge(profile);
```

o así:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(profile);
```

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza  me funciono a la perfección la opcion 2. Gracias.